# Port to iOS from Java on top of libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

How to port to iOS from Java on top of libgdx?

What IDE should I use?

Is there any video or just plain text tutrials on this?

PS

After reading tutorial [code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/IOSWIP](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/IOSWIP) I've understood that libGDX does not suite my needs. I've found the alternative way to "convert" Java to Objective-C such as j2objc [code.google.com/p/j2objc](http://code.google.com/p/j2objc). It suites my needs better. May be somebody else find it better as well.

Comment: Your question is rather broad and imprecise for Stack Overflow.  Have you read the documentation?  (see https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/IOSWIP)  Do you have an existing Java app or are you writing a new app?

Comment: This documentation is the answer, thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's not a matter of what IDE you use, any Java IDE will suffice although I personally would recommend you using one of the major ones like Eclipse or IntelliJ.

When compiling to iOS you'll have to use Xamarin to "convert" and compile your game to iOS. You can read it in more detail here : https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/IOSWIP

Comment: Thanks, pedronveloso. I've found the alternative way to "convert" Java to Objective-C such as j2objc https://code.google.com/p/j2objc. It suites my needs better. May be somebody else find it better too.